# How to search in multi column?

Tags: laravel

I need to search in `users` table with the name and if there no match with any name in table transfer into category table which has relation with each one of user.

the code of html:

```
 <form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="GET">
   <input type="search" class="input" name="q" placeholder="Search">
 </form>
```

Controller code (my shut):

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
  $users = new User;

  $req = $request->input('q');

  $users = $users->where('name','LIKE','%'. $req .'%')->whereHas('category', function ($query) use($req) {
    $query->where('name','LIKE','%'. $req .'%');
  });

  $users = $users->unverified()->active()->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(16);
  return view('frontend.search.search', compact('users'));

}
```

category has relation with user:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

I need to say if there is no name ( users table )  check the category one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a orWhere method, which means or do the other. To avoid weird logic it is the easiest approach to wrap it in a where closure.

```
$users = User::where(function ($query) use($req) {
    $query->where('name','LIKE','%'. $req .'%')
        ->orWhereHas('category', function ($query) use($req) {
            $query->where('name','LIKE','%'. $req .'%');
        });
});
```

This means your code will find elements with the name or with the given category. There is an edge case where it will find by the category name even if user is set. But avoiding that, is not as straight forward as this.

Comment: So, what the different between where()->where() and where()->orwhere() ?

Comment: and with your code got this error ( Undefined variable: users ) in this line (    $users->where('name','LIKE','%'. $req .'%') )

Comment: I assumed you pasted it into your snippet, but my snippet is updated. The difference is where()->where() will produce the sql "where name = x and category.name = x" with the orWhere it will produce ""where name = x or category.name = x""

Comment: thank you so much, just edit the second $users to $query in second line of your code, and again thanks

Comment: Yh found it and had it updated, stupid copy paste error. Did it help your problem?